# On a problem of connectedness in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

I'm trying to solve a problem from the book "Foundations of real and abstract analysis" by Douglas Bridges. I'm asking here because I think a have a solution to the excersice but I'm not quite sure about it. Here is the problem:

Let $S$ be a connected subset of the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ . Prove that for each $r>0$ the set

$$T=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}: \rho(x,S)\leq r\}$$
is also connected.

Here, we define $\rho(x,S)=\inf\{\rho(x,s):s\in S\}$ is the distance from the point x to the set S.

Here is my attempt: Suppose, for the sake of getting a contradiction, that there is $r>0$ for which $S$ is not connected, then there are disjoint open sets $C,D\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $S=(S\cap C)\cup( S\cap D)$ (everything is with the subspace topology) and a continuous function of $S$ onto $\{0,1\}$ given by:

$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
1&\mbox{if } x\in S\cap C\\
0&\mbox{if } x\in S\cap D
\end{array}\right.$$

Note that $S\subset A$ (the set $A$ is like a band around the set $S$ with distance $r$). Also, the restriction $f|_{S}$ is continous with respect to the subspace topology and

$$f|_{S}(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
1&\mbox{if } x\in T\cap S\cap C\\
0&\mbox{if } x\in T\cap S\cap D
\end{array}\right.$$
is a continous function of $S$ onto $\{0,1\}$, but this is a contradiction since $S$ is connected, hence $A$ is connected.

Is my argument correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $T=\{x: d(x,S)<r\}$ is not connected and consider a surjective continuous function $f:T\rightarrow \{0,1\}$. Let $x,y\in T$ such that $f(x)=0, f(y)=1$.

There exists $a\in S$ such that $\|x-a\|<r$, consider $a_t= a+t(x-a), t\leq 1$, $\|a_t-a\|<r$ implies that $a_t\in T$, we have $f(a_t)=f(a)=f(x)=0=f(a)$ since $\{a+t(x-a)\}$ is connected.

Similarly, let $b\in S$ with $d(b,y)<r$, write $b_t=b+t(y-b)$, $b_t\in T$ and $f(b_t)=f(b)=1$.

Since the restriction of $f$ to $S$ is continuous and $S$ is connected, it is constant contradiction since $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=1$.

Comment: Thank you!!! I understood completely! Also, I loved your proof, it is very elegant
I've been trying this excersice for days without any success